# Is there support for Turkish language?

Tags: app-actions

The docs implies that there's no support for non-english locales but I can clearly search "something" on Gmail using Google Assistant. My understanding is that it translates my command to English and then executes it.
The main problem is that I want to "call" someone in my app but in Turkish "call" also means "search". So I can't use `CREATE_CALL` bult-in-intent... Any suggestions?

Also; I know Dialogflow allows developers to define other pronunciations for application name, is there anything similar in App Actions specifically?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? If I good understand you want to use Dialogflow with Actions SDK. Dialogflow supports turkish `Text`, `STT`, `TTS` and `Phone`. Could you provide more details about your issue and how it's working now and how you would expect to work?

Comment: @PjoterS , I want to invoke one of my app's features with Google Assistant but there's two problems; the pronunciation of my app's name is very similar to "Highly" so Assistant can't differentiate them. The second problem is that I want to use App Actions' BIIs in Turkish. Is there a workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if I understand you have your application in Turkish language? Would it be possible to use english in your device and in the application? Name of your application is very similar to `Highly` and Google Assistant cannot distinguish them. What error are you getting? Did you get an error mentioned in [this troubleshoot guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/troubleshoot)? What is your query? `Call employee on <yourAppName>`? Currently BIIs in Turkish are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With App Actions, each BII has different language support.  You will need to consult the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents) for your chosen BII to find out what languages it supports.  You can see from the [CREATE_CALL docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/communications/create-call) that Turkish is not supported.  In fact, current, Turkish is not supported by any BII.

The way voice is handled in Google applications is not necessarily any indication of how App Actions can work for your app.  If you don't see it in the docs, then it's not supported.